# New google cloud instance with no ping no ssh after import from LCX container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lxc, google-compute-engine, proxmox

I would like to migrate from my ProxMox server to Google Cloud Engine service. I tried to create an image from one LCX container then import on Google cloud.

I did these steps:

- create a backup from LCX container (with entire filesystem)
- from the backup I create a raw image using *dd* linux command
- I import the raw image into Google Storage bucket
- I create a Google VM instance from the imported image

After this I get the new instance but I'm not able to ping or connect via ssh. I notice that after few minutes the instance stops automatically.

Instead if I create another instance from a default template (example: Debian 9) I have no problem with ping and connection.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the serial console logs from your instance? This will reveal how far the boot-up of the new instance gets.

Comment: but without ssh connect I'm not able to connect to the server and see the log...

Comment: On GCE the serial console is accessible via `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output`, The "Serial Port 1 (console)" link on the VM instance details page in the cloud console or the [getSerialPortOutput API call](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/getSerialPortOutput)

Answer (score 0):

You should reconfigure the networking inside that instance after you have started it in GCE. Being imported from a LXC container from Proxmox, it still has the settings from LXC so probably your networking interface is not configured properly or with the correct ip address so it can function in GCE

Comment: The main problem is that I have no access through ssh so I have no idea about how reconfigure the network properties...
Alternatively which properties are correct in order to do a snapshot from proxmox and after import in GCE, do not have any more problems?

Comment: I haven't used GCE that much but I suppose you should have some console access or anything similar...